# UISlider not updating values

Tags: swift, uislider

apologies if this is a stupid question. I can't seem to get my slider to update  its value as its being interacted with. (I'm going to point everyone to the very last method in this long code)

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.size.height = 7
        return rect
    }
}

class FactionButton: CustomSlider {
    var factionSlider = CustomSlider(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 542, width: 386, height: 57))

    func factionBalanceSlider(){
        factionSlider.minimumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Alliance Slider")
        factionSlider.maximumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Horde Slider")
        factionSlider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Thumb Image"), for: .normal)
        factionSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.33, blue:0.69, alpha:0.8)
        factionSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.59)

        factionSlider.setValue(0.5, animated: true)
        factionSlider.isContinuous = false

        factionSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordFactionBalance(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func getSlider() -> CustomSlider {
        return factionSlider
    }

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var customBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        customBounds.size.height = 10
        return customBounds
    }

    @objc func recordFactionBalance(sender: CustomSlider){
        //also calculates balance and adds it into the quiz data
        print("hi")
        print(sender.value) //It's this part that doesn't work 

    }

}
```

It's this bit nearest to the bottom that has the issue. (Everything else is fine) The action function doesn't seem to be triggered at all, even when I'm interacting with it. Neither print statements are being executed. Any ideas why?

Cheers

Comment: Since `isContinuous = false`, is it not printing after the sliding is completed? Where are you calling `factionBalanceSlider`? Probably you forgot to add that part in question?

Comment: @adev I considered both of them, unfortunately re: isContinuous - I did try it declared true and false and neither fixed it. re: slider function - I called it in my viewDidLoad :(

Comment: move your initialisation code to `override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        minimumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Alliance Slider")
        maximumValueImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Horde Slider")
 setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Thumb Image"), for: .normal)
 minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.33, blue:0.69, alpha:0.8)
 maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.59)
 
 setValue(0.5, animated: true)
 isContinuous = false
 
 addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordFactionBalance), for: .valueChanged)
}`

Comment: and set your frame there also `frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 542, width: 386, height: 57)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `getSlider()`, i can guess you are using this `class` as a utility to get the `CustomSlider`. So, i suspect you are adding the slider to the `view` as below,

```
let container = FactionButton()
container.factionBalanceSlider()
let slider = container.getSlider()

self.view.addSubview(slider)
```

If you will not add the `container` to the `view` which is set as the receiver for `.valueChange` event so it will not get any event. To receive events you also need to add the `container` in the `view` as below,

```
self.view.addSubview(container)
```